# How to transfer ownership from a vector of shared pointers to another one?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm trying to understand what is the best way in C++ to pass data around. In the following example I'm trying to pass ownership of the data (Shader) to a class (ShaderProgram).

I could do this with raw pointers, but that adds the need to manage it's life-cycle which I'm not looking to do. Unfortunately I'm getting a `read access violation` when inside the method I try to move the shared pointer.

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<ShaderProgram> modelShaders; // this is inside another class, but I guess it's not too important

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Shader> vert = std::make_shared<Shader>(Shader::VERTEX, std::string("res/shaders/model/basic.vert"));
    std::shared_ptr<Shader> frag = std::make_shared<Shader>(Shader::FRAGMENT, std::string("res/shaders/model/basic.frag"));

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shader>> shaders;

    shaders.push_back(std::move(vert));
    shaders.push_back(std::move(frag));

    modelShaders->compileShaders( shaders );
}
```

```cpp
    // std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shader>> m_shaders; definition inside the class

void ShaderProgram::compileShaders(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shader>> &shaders)
{
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();

    for (auto shaderIter = shaders.begin(); shaderIter != shaders.end(); shaderIter++)
    {
        std::shared_ptr shader = *shaderIter;

        GLuint shaderID = compileShader(shader);

        GL(glAttachShader(program, shaderID));

        shader->setID(shaderID);

        m_shaders.push_back(std::move(shader)); // here I get a read access violation
    }
```

My purpose is avoiding creating/destroying classes without the need of it. I don't want the Shader instances to be destroyed or copied around.

PS: If anyone can recommend some articles, etc.. on the topic of passing data around, that would be great!

### EDIT

```cpp
class ShaderProgram
{
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shader>> m_shaders;
public:
    ShaderProgram()
        : m_id(0) {};
    ~ShaderProgram() {
        std::cout << "[ShaderProgram] destroyed" << std::endl;
    };

    ...

    GLuint compileShader(const std::shared_ptr<Shader>& shader);
    void compileShaders(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shader>> &shaders);

   ...
```

```cpp
GLuint ShaderProgram::compileShader(const std::shared_ptr<Shader> &shader) {

    GLuint id = 0;
    std::string src = shader->getSource();

    const char* cSrc = src.c_str();

    GL((id = glCreateShader(shader->getGLType())));
    GL(glShaderSource(id, 1, &cSrc, NULL));
    GL(glCompileShader(id));

    if (GetStatus(id, Status::SHADER, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, shader->getName(), "COMPILATION FAILURE") != GL_TRUE)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}
```

Comment: It seems you want using of `std:: unique_ptr`, not `std::shared_ptr`. The piece of code that you posted looks correct, the reason of access violation may be in another part of the code. Try to make [mcve].

Comment: @S.M.: Given the OpenGL, I rather suspect that he really does want `shared_ptr`. The code is still really wrong, but I can see the "logic" behind it.

Comment: What does `compileShader`?

Comment: @S.M. I've added more code and edited the first one for clarity.

Comment: I suppose you need a reference `std::shared_ptr &shader`. I still can't see the reason of access violation.

Comment: @S.M. It's something to do with `m_shaders`. It crashes with read access violation every time I try to call a method on it. Would `ShaderProgram` being itself a `shared_ptr` create any issue like this? Also, I'm not initializing `m_shaders` with the constructor.

Comment: It looks like the object of `ShaderProgram` died and you have a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shader>> m_shaders;` not being initialized in the constructor. I was under the pressure this was taken care automatically by `<vector>`, but it wasn't the case. By adding the following code, everything worked as expected:

```cpp
    ShaderProgram() : m_shaders(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shader>>()) {};
```